# Java best practices static final map values

Tags: java, optimization

I have a utility class which contains a static final map with some values. I need to access to this map in another class. Should I just declare the map as public, or should I write a getter inside the utility class, and therefore let the map be private?

Both ways work, but what are the best practices?

```
public MyUtilityClass {
  public static final Map<String, Integer> MAX_LENGTHS = ImmutableMap.of(
      "title", 256,
      "text", 512);

}

public MyAnotherClass {

  public void someMethod() {
    //accessing the map directly
    MAX_LENGTHS.get("title")
  }

}
```

Or

```
public MyUtilityClass {
  private static final Map<String, Integer> MAX_LENGTHS = ImmutableMap.of(
      "title", 256,
      "text", 512);

  public static final getMaxLengthMap() {return MAX_LENGTHS;}
}

public MyAnotherClass {
  public void someMethod() {
    //accessing the map directly
    getMaxLengthMap().get("title")
  }
}
```

Well, actually the keys are enum values.
Something like :

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> MAX_LENGTHS = ImmutableMap.of(
      MyEnumClass.TITLE, 256,
      MyEnumClass.TEXT, 512);
```

Comment: A "getter" on `MyUtilityClass` should probably return the value of key, rather then users of the class having to know what they keys are or how they are stored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `ImmutableMap` from `guava` project; thus a *true* immutable `Map`.

Making it `public` would not hurt anyone - as no one can really alter that `Map` in any way.

Answer (score 5):

The getter does not add anything - I would just keep it public.

What may make sense is to have a method that returns the value directly:

```
public MyUtilityClass {
  private static final Map<String, Integer> MAX_LENGTHS = ImmutableMap.of(
      "title", 256,
      "text", 512);

  public static final getMaxLength(String item) {return MAX_LENGTHS.get(item);}
}

public MyAnotherClass {
  public void someMethod() {
    //accessing the map directly
    getMaxLength("title");
  }
}
```

This also allows you to easily modify the underlying implementation later on. For example you could return a default value for items not in the map etc.

Comment: You are going to litter this utility class with `Map`'s methods... Tomorrow I will want `containsKey` from `MAX_LENGTHS`, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: This is also the way to go when defining custom mapping functions in enums as `valueOf` throws on wrong names.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko add another method. This is not littering. Consider an enum (if you have to enumerate values) or use multiple helper classes.

Comment: @roookeee I believe it is... You are about to write a bunch of Map's methods just to back up **one** private field. What if the class had other fields/methods that are not Map-related (which is highly likely for a utility class)? (I used to employ this approach, now I don't find anything good about it)

Comment: "This also allows you to easily modify the underlying implementation later on." I am wondering how it's important... It's a utility class used internally and won't be exposed publicly, right?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I'm not saying it should be done that way - I'm merely giving the OP one more option. Based on this simple example I agree that a public field is completely fine.

Comment: @assylias yes that's a good point. I need to think about it, if I need to return a default value or not. If I don't need it then I'll just let it be public since it's immutable.

Comment: I would always opt for the implementation which only exposes the required data. I would let the helper function return an `Optional` as not every possible `String` is mapped which already offers applying additonal fallback logic without exposing the internal data structure

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that you're probably just better of using an `Enum` in the first place. As this mapping seems to be always completly static:

```
public enum MaxLength {
    TITLE(256),
    TEXT(512);

    public final int value;

    MaxLength(int value) {
        this.value= value;
    }
}
```

No more need for that utility class, you can now just get the value directly:

```
int length = MaxLength.TITLE.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do with your map.
Allowing accessing it directly to map (so setting that as public), will give anyone the possibility do use and modify that map without any restriction.

In your case the map is final and immutable, so this won't apply.

But if you want to restrict that access only to some of its content, like the `title`, then the right choice is to create a method that will return only a `String`.

Setting the map to public, or creating a method which return the whole map makes no difference.

Comment: The map is immutable so your first points don't apply.

Comment: @Leviand _modify that map without any restriction_ not for the Map OP is using.

Comment: You are right, I've fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a getter to the owning class would be the way to go.

```
public MyUtilityClass {
  private static final Map<String, Integer> MAX_LENGTHS = ImmutableMap.of(
      "title", 256,
      "text", 512);

  public static int getLength(final String key) {
     return MAX_LENGTHS.get(key);
  }
}

public MyAnotherClass {
  public void someMethod() {

    int x= MyUtilityClass.getLength("title")
  }
}
```

This insulates `MyAnotherClass` from needing to know any implementation details of the getter and makes mocking for testing much easier.